# Using JQuery to increase input by 1 limiting to 9 and concatenating to hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to use plus/minus to increase/decrease numbers by 0-9 then continually concatenate the input values to one hidden input that will be submitted into the CMS.

JSFiddle is here and currently can't limit numbers and unable to concatenate the values.

https://jsfiddle.net/c06sy673/2/

```
//Script for concatinating counter1 and counter2
$(document).click(function() {
  var value1 = $('.counter1').val();
  var value2 = $('.counter2').val();

  $(".output").val(value1 + value2);
});

//Script for increasing value increment by +1 and preventing numbers below 0
$(function() {

  $("form .counter-inner").append('<div class="inc increment_button">+</div><div class="dec increment_button">-</div>');
  $(".increment_button").on("click", function() {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
      // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
      } else {
        newVal = 0;
      }
    }

    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
  });
});
```

```css
.counter-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.inc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 0px;
}
.dec {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 32px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  font-size: 90px;
  line-height: 0px;
}
.counter {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  cursor: auto;
  font-size: 130px;
  width: 187px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  height: 280px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.increment_button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.counter-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="counter-wrapper">
    <label for="name">Team 1</label>
    <div class="counter-inner">
      <input type="text" name="team_1--count1 increment" class="counter counter1" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="counter-inner">
      <input type="text" name="team_1--count2 increment" class="counter counter2" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="counter-wrapper">
    <label for="name">Team 1</label>
    <div class="counter-inner">
      <input type="text" name="team_1--count1 increment" class="counter counter3" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="counter-inner">
      <input type="text" name="team_1--count2 increment" class="counter counter4" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>


  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>


<p class="output"></p>
```

Apologies in advance if I'm just missing something really obvious!

Comment: Concatenated or Incremented/Decremented?

Comment: change to `$(".output").text(value1 + value2);` , you have to use `.text()` , not `val()`  [https://jsfiddle.net/c06sy673/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/c06sy673/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/c06sy673/6/

```
//Script for concatinating counter1 and counter2
$(document).click(function () {
            var value1 = $('.counter1').val();
            var value2 = $('.counter2').val();
            $(".output").text(value1 + value2);
        });
//Script for increasing value increment by +1 and preventing numbers below 0
          $(function () {
            $("form .counter-inner").append('<div class="inc increment_button">+</div><div class="dec increment_button">-</div>');
            $(".increment_button").on("click", function () {
                var $button = $(this);
                var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
                if ($button.text() == "+") {
                        if(oldValue < 9){
                        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
                    }else{
                      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Don't allow decrementing below zero
                    if (oldValue > 0) {
                        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
                    } else {
                        newVal = 0;
                    }
                }
                $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks an absolute tonne @miglio, that's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your

```
if ($button.text() == "+") {
  var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
}
```

to

```
if ($button.text() == "+") {
  var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) < 9 ? parseFloat(oldValue) + 1 : parseFloat(oldValue);
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c06sy673/3/)

Comment: Thanks @rmondesilva that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

replace

> var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;

whit

> var temp = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
>        newVal=temp<=9?temp:9;

this should limit the number to 9.

but i am not sure what do you mean by "concatenate the values".